# How to save unrelated entities in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have 3 entities such that parent entity contains `list<child1>` entities and `list<child2>` entities.

Until now the problem was simple.

Simply adding `List<child1>` inside parent entity would entirely save parent-Child1 entities.

But the problem is each entity of `Child1` has a foreign key of child2's primary key. How can I save the data in one short.

My entities are :

```
public class Consignment
{
    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public int ClientSubsidiaryId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PackagingAid> PackagingAids { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConsignmentLine> ConsignmentLines { get; set; }    

    public Consignment()
    {
        PackagingAids = new List<PackagingAid>();
        ConsignmentLines = new List<ConsignmentLine>();            
    }
}

public class ConsignmentLine
{
    public int ConsignmentLineId { get; set; }
    public int PackagingId { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }                

    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Consignment Consignment { get; set; }

    public int? PackagingAidId { get; set; }
    public virtual PackagingAid PackagingAid { get; set; }
}

public class PackagingAid
{
    public int PackagingAidId { get; set; }

    public int PackagingId { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    public int ConsignmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Consignment Consignment { get; set; }
}
```

Now if try to do something like this

```
consignments = new List<Consignment>();

for(int i = 0;i<500; i++)
{
    var consignment = new Consignment()
    {
      ConsignmentLines = new List<ConsignmentLine>(){ line1, line2,... }
      PackagingAids = new List<PackagingAid>() { aid1, aid2, aid3 }
    }
   consignments.Add(consignment);
}

db.context.Consignments.AddRange(consignments);
db.context.SaveChanges(); //  throws an exception { cannot insert PackagingAid into ConsignmentLine.PackagingAidId.....}
```

I know the procedure would be simply first saving all consignments without `Consignmentlines`. After that for each consignment Id , I will have to create consignmentLines. But I don't want this.

I want all in one go. How can I solve this? Feel free to let me know in case if something is not clear.